# How to compare a template template with a template instance?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, c++14

First, let me introduce you a partial solution:

```
template <template <class...> class,
        typename ...>
struct is_tbase_of:
  std::false_type
{ };

template <template <class...> class Type,
          typename ...Args>
struct is_tbase_of<Type, Type<Args...>>:
  std::true_type
{ };
```

In common cases, it works:

```
is_tbase_of<std::vector, std::is_integral<int>>::value; // false
is_tbase_of<std::vector, std::vector<int>>::value;      // true
```

But, it does not work on a «meta-returned» template template, for example:

```
template <template <class ...> class T>
struct quote
{
  template <typename ...U>
  using type = T<U...>;
};

using QVec =  quote<std::vector>;
is_tbase_of<QVec::template type, std::vector<int>>::value; // false...
```

I have tried a lot of things, trying to get the second type template arguments (to compare the quoted type specialization) but it seems I can't get them to work.  Even specializing `is_tbase_of` for `quote` (which would be a less general but sufficient option) seems to send me to the black corners of template pattern-matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if you can change `U<Args...>` to `T<Args...>` and then check if the result stays the same:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct is_tbase_of_impl
{
    struct err {};

    template <template <class...> class T, class U>
    static err test(U*);

    template <template <class...> class T, template <class...> class U, class... Args>
    static T<Args...> test(U<Args...>*);
};

template <template <class...> class T, class U>
using is_tbase_of
    = typename std::is_same< decltype(is_tbase_of_impl::test<T>((U*)0)), U >::type;

template <template <class...> class T>
struct quote
{
    template <class... U>
    using type = T<U...>;
};

using QVec = quote<std::vector>;

template <class...> struct S {};

static_assert( !is_tbase_of< std::vector, std::is_integral<int>  >::value, "" );
static_assert(  is_tbase_of< std::vector, std::vector<int>       >::value, "" );
static_assert(  is_tbase_of< QVec::type,  std::vector<int>       >::value, "" );
static_assert( !is_tbase_of< std::vector, S<int, int, int>       >::value, "" );

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Clever.  However, [there is a small hole](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6ef3ae1217de2c6).  Very small, not worth wondering about, but look at that last assert.  Amusingly if the arguments to `S` are the same as the arguments to `S2_`, the `static_assert` fails!

Comment: Very nice :-) Less surprising, but this `template <class...> using S2 = void;` will always fail...

Comment: I think this cannot generate a false positive, however.  Here is a question: does your solution ever result in a different answer than [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28865203/1774667)?  And if so, who is more correct?  (I actually think the answer is "no")

Comment: I thought you meant that `is_tbase_of<S2,S2<int,void>` _looks like_ it should return true (with your `S2`), but this effectively calls `is_tbase_of<S2,S<int>>` With `template <class...> using V = void` it is always `is_tbase_of<V,V</*args...*/>> = false` though it _looks like_ it should always return true.

Comment: *nod*.  A false positive would be a case where it *does* return `true`, but it should have returned false.  Both the `S2` and the `V` cases return false, even though it looks like it should return true.  If I replace `type = S<int>` with `type = S<int,void>` in the `S2` case, the return value does become `true`, but it isn't a "false" positive in that `S2<int,void>` does produce `S2<int,void>`.  I guess `is_tbase_of<S2, S<int,void>>` is a false positive (with `type=S<int,void>`) in a sense?

Comment: Or, [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/385fd15020062cd1) of a "false positive" in the test, rather than talking about it just show it.

Comment: Yes, indeed, looks like this should return false, but correctly returns true.

Answer (score 4):

This is an attempt to solve the problem with direct template structure metaprogramming and SFINAE.

The plan is 2 fold.  First, a traits class that takes a template and a pack of arguments, and answers "is it legal to apply the pack of arguments to the template".  This is a surprisingly useful structure: as an example, given a SFINAE friendly `result_of_t<F(Args...)>`, you can write `can_invoke<F(Args...)>` in one line.

Second, we write `is_template_instance_of`.  The goal here is to take a `T<Args...>` type and a `Z<?...>` template, and see if `Z<Args...>` is the same type as `T<Args...>`.  We use the above `can_apply` traits class to guard against illegal substitution, then do a simple `is_same` test.

The solution generates a few false positives and negatives, depending on how you look at it.  Basically if the template `Z<?...>` we are matching against is an alias template that isn't a direct alias, it won't work the way you might expect.  If it is a direct alias, you are going to be good.

Without further ado, here is the implementation.

First, Boilerplate types pack:

```
template<class...>struct types {using type=types;};
```

In C++1z has `void_t`, I reimplemented it here:

```
template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

given `Z<?...>` and `types<Ts...>`, check if `Z<Ts...>` is valid:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class types, class=void>
struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct can_apply<Z, types<Ts...>, void_t<Z<Ts...>>> : std::true_type {};
```

Now, a SFINAE guarded test:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, class=void>
struct is_template_instance_of : std::false_type {};

template<template<class...>class Z, template<class...>class Y, class... Ts>
struct is_template_instance_of<
  Z, Y<Ts...>,
  std::enable_if_t<can_apply< Z, types<Ts...> >{}>
> : std::is_same< Z<Ts...>, Y<Ts...> > {};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69f66d492104eff0)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your original implementation doesn't work is that, even though `QVec::type<Args...>` is the same type as `std:vector<Args...>`, `QVec::type` is not the same **template** as `std::vector`, so it doesn't match the partial specialization.

This can be seen with a simpler example:

```
template <template <typename...> class> struct test {
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct test<std::vector> {
  static const bool value = true;
};

test<std::vector>::value; // true
test<QVec::type>::value;  // false
```

Here is one approach that almost works:

```
template <template <class...> class Type1,
          template <class...> class Type2,
          typename... Args>
struct is_tbase_of<Type1, Type2<Args...>>:
  std::is_same<Type1<Args...>,Type2<Args...>>
{
};
```

However, as noted by @Alex, this doesn't handle the case where the arguments to the second template are not compatible with the first template. This can be solved using `enable_if`:

```
template <template <class...> class, typename, typename=void>
struct is_tbase_of : std::false_type { };

template <template <class...> class Type1,
          template <class...> class Type2,
          typename... Args>
struct is_tbase_of<Type1, Type2<Args...>,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<Type1<Args...>,Type2<Args...>>::value
  >::type>
  : std::true_type
{
};
```

Comment: Ok but this only works if `Type1<Args...>` is valid. Otherwise this results in a compiler error.

Comment: If only SFINAE worked for partial template specialization selection as well

Comment: @Joe how does it not work for partial template specialization?  The problem above is that the part after the `:` isn't subject to SFINAE, where the substitution occurs.

Comment: @Yakk There is no place within the body of the struct where SFINAE can occur which would prevent the specialization from being used, right?

Comment: @joe not that I know of.  Just the immediate context of the substitution, which is defined in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

If specializing `is_tbase_of` for `quote` is sufficient, this should work:

```
template <template <class...> class Type,
          typename ...Args>
struct is_tbase_of<quote<Type>::template type, Type<Args...>>:
  std::true_type
{ };
```